# Basic question: what does the notation $[A,B]$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

If $A$ and $B$ are both matrices, what is $[A,B]$? I understand that it is a commutator and that $[A,B]=AB-BA$, but since I don't know what a commutator is, none of this information is telling me much.

Comment: You said it yourself: it is $AB - BA$, and it's called a commutator.  What more do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. What I was wondering was whether [A,B] represented any sort of abstract concept, outside the definition [A,B] = AB - BA. But it seems that it does not. Thank you very much!

Comment: This notation is also used more generally for the Lie bracket of a [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra). And indeed, this binary operation turns square matrices into a Lie algebra.

Answer (score 5):

As you note: $[A, B] = AB - BA$. Rather than spell out the way to compute it every time we refer to it, we simply call $[A, B]$ the [commutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator).

As you see if you explore the link above, is that commutators exist in many contexts, not just when discussing matrices.

> "In mathematics, *the commutator gives an indication of the extent to which a certain binary operation* ***fails to be commutative***. There are different definitions used in group theory and ring theory."

I'd suggest you read the Wikipedia entry and particularly, note that the commutator of two elements $a$ and $b$ of a ring or an ***associative algebra*** is defined by $$ [a, b] = ab − ba. $$

Answer (score 3):

It means exactly what you say. $[A,B]$ is precisely $AB - BA$, and people happen to call it the commutator.

Answer (score 2):

Math objects which obey the commutative property of multiplication satisfy $ab=ba$, and therefore $ab-ba=0$.

Matrix multiplication does not satisfy the commutative property so in general $AB\neq BA$, therefore $AB-BA \neq 0$. Because this form of expression comes up a lot, mathematicians invented a compact notation for it: $[A,B] \equiv AB-BA$, which is called "the commutator of $A$ and $B$."

Like Robert and mixedmath said already, there is nothing to understand here --- it is just a definition.

Comment: do you know if this definition was created for matrices specifically first or for Lie algebras?